# UITextView magnifying glass not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is a problem:

I have a UITextView as a `messageField` inside UIView `toolBar`. The `toolBar` is added as an accessory view:

```
- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView
{
    return self.toolBar;
}
```

When I do a long touch on a `messageField`, **NO magnifying glass** comes on. But **only when I release the finger**, I see **magnifying glass appears for just a millisecond and then disappears right away**, and the only thin I see after are options like "Select, Select All, etc"

**Why is magnifying glass not appearing during a long touch ???**

Comment: Are you testing in simulator or device ?

Comment: Always work with a real device.